# Get real timestamp of frame captured using OpenCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I'm using EmguCv wrapper for OpenCV to capture live video from IP camera.

I'm trying to get the frame timestamp using the function

```
Capture _Capture = new Capture(URL);
_Capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;

private void _Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Mat Frame;
   _Capture.Retrieve(Frame);
   double ts = GetCaptureProperty(CapProp.PosMsec);
}
```

the function work, but it return the position of the frame from the beggining of the capturing and not the device clock timestamp.

in the [manual of the EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/index.html) and OpenCV its says:

> GetCaptureProperty(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) is returning the film current position in milliseconds or video capture timestamp

Is there a way to choose if it will return the film position or the timestamp?

Thanks